# Creating a .csv file with an utf-8 delimiter

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, multibyte

I'm trying to create a `.csv` file by pulling data from an `Oracle DB`. 
And, I need to delimit the `file` with a `thorn` character.

Error is:

```
Its outside the range 128.
```

Is there any way I can create a `csv` with a `multibyte delimiter`?

Comment: Show us the code, specifically a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can use print function with " thorn" as separator and redirect to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed write UTF-8 strings with the csv module, but you cannot pass unicode strings containing non ASCII characters to a csv writer. The doc for the `writerow(row)` function states : *A row must be a sequence of strings or numbers for Writer objects and a dictionary mapping fieldnames to strings or numbers (**by passing them through str() first**) for DictWriter objects*. (emphasis is mine).
So, you must first encode values :

```
writer.writerow([ val.encode('utf8') if isinstance(val, unicode) else val for val in row ])
```

Same for the separator do not use a unicode string, but the encoded string : to use the thorn as separator :

```
wr = csv.writer(fd, delimiter = u'\xfe'.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the second method, as I just needed the delimiter. I got the error:  c = csv.writer(open(oFile, 'wb'), delimiter=u'\xfe'.encode('utf8'))
TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string.                               Could you help me out on this? I'm very new to Python. 2-3 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

In latin1 encoding the thorn character, `þ`, is only one byte, so the following worked for me using Python 2.7.10:

```
# -*- coding: latin1 -*-

import csv

with open('unitest.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='þ')
    writer.writerow([1,2,3,'a','b','c'])
```

Contents of csv file created:

```
1þ2þ3þaþbþc
```